# What is the significance of 9+2 arrangement in flagella?

Tags: cell-biology

Why eukaryotic flagella have 9+2 arrangement .? What is the significance?  a 9+0  flagella should have worked the same way .

Comment: What do you mean by 'normal flagella'?